# solving a system consist of coupled differential equations and a square wave function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I encountered a system which is consist of coupled differential equations and a square wave function.

This system is consist of 3 coupled differential equation, while the value of one of the "constant parameter" of the differential equations is changing periodically like a square wave: first half of the period has a value, and rest half of the period has another value.

$$\frac{dj}{dt} = 2L\sqrt2xj\\
\frac{dx}{dt} = p-\frac{k}{2}x\\
\frac{dp}{dt} = -x-\frac{k}{2}p-2L\sqrt2j$$
$$L=L(f+2\pi)=L(f)= \begin{cases} 
1, 0\leq f<\pi\\
0, \pi\leq f<2\pi
\end{cases}$$

I am really running of idea for how to include the changing value of into a differential equation. Thanks in advance of any answer.

Comment: Solve the equation on $0\leq f<\pi$, with initial conditions at $f=0$, then $\pi\leq f<2\pi$, with arbitrary initial conditions at $f=\pi$, and then "patch them together" choose the initial conditions at $f=\pi$ to match the final values of your solution on $(0,\pi)$.

Comment: what do you mean by patch them together?

Comment: Somewhere I dropped a colon.  What I mean by "patch them together" is "choose the initial conditions at $f=\pi$ to match the final values of your solution on $(0,\pi)$."  An example of this appears in Wikipedia's treatment of the Schrödinger equation for the finite potential well, [§Finding wavefunctions for the bound state](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Finite_potential_well&oldid=1078545138#Finding_wavefunctions_for_the_bound_state)